# How do I enable *PerformanceOverlayLayer.checkerboardOffscreenLayers* in flutter profile mode

Tags: flutter

[image: flutter documentation]

see https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/ui-performance
How to enable this **switch**?

Answer (score 12):

In the constructor of MaterialApp, there is a bool option called `checkerboardOffscreenLayers`.
[image]